# Java - Class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, class

I'm tasked with making a basic constructor like this. I've looked at tutorials online and I believe this is how it should look like, though I'm quite new to this so I could be wrong.

```
public class V10String implements Set<String>{
    private AVLTreeNode<String> tree;
    private int size;

    public int height;
    public String val;
    public AVLTreeNode left,right;
    public V10String()
    {
      AVLTreeNode tree = new AVLTreeNode();
      int size=0;
    }

    public class AVLTreeNode<String>
    {
      public int height;
      public String val;
      public AVLTreeNode left,right;

    }
}
```

The error occurs at the `AVLTreeNode<String>`. I'm implementing this:

```
public interface Set<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
{
    // Irrelevant functions
}
```

The goal is that the user be able to create an empty V10String instance, which consists of an empty tree node.

Comment: `public AVLTreeNode<String>` is invalid syntax.  What exactly are you trying to do here?  The compiler is wondering too.

Comment: Are you trying to define a nested class?

Comment: I apologize, I thought this was how classes worked. The user instantiates a V10String class, and that object contains an AVLTreeNode object. @pbabcdefp Yes

Answer (score 0):

```
public AVLTreeNode<String>
```

Whats that? you don't give it a name, value (in case it's a variable) or arguments (in case of method). And you still make a block???

BTW if this was a method, `public` on the fields in the block is irrelevant.

Comment: `public` is *very much* relevant.

Comment: @Makoto I said __in the block fields__